# Is it better to have an onClick() method for each element or to implement an OnClickListener and do a switch statement

Tags: java, android, xml, onclick

I'm creating my own Navigation Drawer in my Android app and I was wondering which is better practice.

I can either:

Add a tag in my layout.xml like this `android:onClick="btnHome"`

and then just add the method btnHome() into my .java file.


OR


Give an id to my element like this `android:id="@+id/btnHome"`

Give it an onClickListener `findViewById(R.id.btnHome).setOnClickListener(this);` in my setContentView() or onCreate() method

and then implement the OnClickListener in my class

```java
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnHome:              // The 'Home' button in the navigation drawer
                //TODO: Make it go to home screen
                break;
        }
    }
```

I know both ways can produce the same result but I'm curious if there is any difference between them that I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using "setOnClickListener" is always recommended over "android:onClick". You should create a separate "OnClickListener" for each button, unless all buttons do the same thing or share functionality, which in that case you can just create one "OnClickListener" and assign it to all buttons.
Also use Kotlin and ViewBinding.